# NET 6 Web service: what IP to use for listen?

Tags: asp.net

I develop a NET 6 web service, I have setting in launchsettings.json

```
"applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001/mysvc"
```

My client app connects ok when I run it on the same machine,  But when I run client from other machine and give the address of mysvc machine it cannot connect, I suspect it is because localhost:5001. What address should I use to do mysvc listen on all ip addresses its machine?
I have tried https://*:5001/mysvc but the NET app does not start because of parse error

Answer (score 2):

use `0.0.0.0` to bind on all interfaces, like so :

```json
"applicationUrl": "https://0.0.0.0:5001/mysvc"
```

`0.0.0.0` is the [IPAddress.Any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.any) value

Comment: Set it, run the service, then tried from the local machine: hostname, localhost. 127.0.0.1 do not work anymore.

Comment: It is for run from VS only.